# HQL class selection to DetachedCriteria (stackoverflow on too large ParameterList)

Tags: jakarta-ee, hql, hibernate-tools

I have a serious problem: the ParameterList variable in my HQL has 10k+ elements, so Hibernate can't work with it (stackoverflow), now i'm trying to convert it into DetachedCriteria query, but it's look like this:

```
final StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer(
        "SELECT new db.XXXTable(c.abc1, c.abc2, c.abc3, a.def1, a.def2, a.def3, a.def4, a.def5, a.def6, a.def7, a.def8) FROM def AS a, abc AS c WHERE a.def7 IN (:ids) AND a.def7 =c.abc1 AND a.def9 = TRUE ");

session = getSession();
final Query query = session.createQuery(hql.toString());

query.setParameterList("ids", importIdList);
result = query.list();
```

db.XXXTable has his own constructor.

I saw that maybe the DetachedCriteria query can handle this, but i can't figure it out, how to use it on this (from two tables into a unique class selection...)

But if someone know how to solve the stackoverflow error, it would be also helpfull!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to upgrade to 3.6.9. This version seems to handle 10k+ elements in the parameterList.